# GhostScript execution from php

Tags: php, path, exec

I need to convert pdf files from v1.7 to v1.4 since PDF parser has errors on 1.7 files (missing catalog etc). I've installed GhostScript under CentOS 7. Now I need to exec a GhostScript command from php.

My php file is inside a restricted access dir under public dir, let's say commandsdir.

My pdf files are in a path like the following: subdir_lev1/subdir_lev_2/file_to_convert.pdf .

I have a command to perform that is:

```
exec('gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH 
-sOutputFile=new_path/new_file.pdf old_path/old_file.pdf');
```

If I use:

```
<?php
exec('gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH 
-sOutputFile=../subdir_lev1/subdir_lev_2/new_file.pdf
../subdir_lev1/subdir_lev_2/file_to_convert.pdf');
?>
```

the command does not get any result. No errors are thrown. No new file is written. The command seems to be executed, since it uses some seconds, but after that nothing happens. I suspect that is simply a matter of path. So, what's the exact syntax to use for the path of the file to convert and for the path of the new file?

Comment: Did you try using full path for input/output files?

Comment: you mean `https://example.com/subdir_lev1/subdir_lev_2/file_to_convert.pdf` ?

Comment: No, I mean something like `/var/www/html/subdir_lev1/subdir_lev_2/file_to_convert.pdf`.

Comment: Oh yes, yet tried. No result

Comment: So, I guess it is not related to path issue in this case (you can try it in terminal as well and see what is the result)

Comment: already done, and in terminal with the absolute path it gives the expected result perfectly. So as far as executing from php is concerned, it must be something wrong inside the php syntax

Comment: did you solve it back then?